# Numerical evaluation of derivatives of pair

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I have a set of ordered pairs. How can I take calculus action on that like derivative or integration?

$$
N(E) = \{(2, 3), \cdots \} :   N=2 , E=3\\ 
\mathrm dN(E)/\mathrm dE = ? 
$$

Comment: It should be `Divide @@@ Differences[ne]`, where `ne` is your ordered pairs.